# Error while registering android mySQL Volley

Tags: android, mysql, json, nullpointerexception, android-volley

i am new to android this is my first app with mysql database.i am done with login and forget password activities but got stuck in registration.I am getting nullPointException and i don't know how to get rid of this.I am sharing my code for registration.java please guide me.

```
public class Resgistration3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    TextView click;
    EditText et_email, et_password;



    SharedPreferences preferences, preferences1, preferences2;
    Button btn_signup;
    SharedPreferences preferences3;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor3;

    EditText et_business, et_Ntn, et_Strn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resgistration3);
        preferences3 = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs2", MODE_PRIVATE);

        et_business = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_business);
        et_Ntn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Ntn);
        et_Strn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Strn);
        btn_signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences1 = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs1", MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences2 = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs2", MODE_PRIVATE);

        et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        btn_signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

        click = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Click);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Resgistration3.this, Screen1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                final String userName = preferences.getString("Name", null);
                final String userEmail = preferences.getString("Email", null);
                final String userPassword = preferences.getString("Password", null);
                final String userMobile = preferences.getString("Mobile", null);
                final String userCity = preferences1.getString("City", null);
                final String userDob = preferences1.getString("Dob", null);
                final String userTax = preferences1.getString("Tax", null);
                final String userCnic = preferences1.getString("Cnic", null);
                final String userBusiness = preferences2.getString("Business", null);
                final String userNtn = preferences2.getString("Ntn", null);

                registerUser(userName,userEmail,userPassword,userMobile,userCity,userDob,userTax,userCnic,userBusiness,userNtn);
                 /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),userName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/


            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(final String userName, final String userEmail, final String userPassword, final String userMobile, final String userCity, final String userDob, final String userTax, final String userCnic, final String userBusiness, final String userNtn) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());


             /*   try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Resgistration3.this, WithoutLogin.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
*/
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("txtemail", userEmail);
                params.put("fname", userName);
                params.put("city", userCity);
                params.put("txtpassword", userPassword);
                params.put("mphone", userMobile);
                params.put("ntn", userNtn);
                params.put("cnic", userCnic);
                params.put("bname", userBusiness);
                params.put("tpay", userTax);
                params.put("dob", userDob);
                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

}
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?PHP

$use_real_escapes = false;
require_once("connection.php");
error_reporting(0);
header( "Content-type: text/json" );    
       if (isset($_POST['fname'])){

    $fnameq = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['fname']);   
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['txtname'] );
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['txtemail'] );
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['city'] );
    $hash = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['txtpassword'] );
    $sk = "I6PnEPbQNLslYMj7ChKxDJ2yenuHLkXn";
    $password = hash('sha512', $hash.$sk);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['phone'] );
    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['mphone'] );
    $ntn = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['ntn'] );
    $strn = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['strn'] );
    $cnic = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['cnic'] );
    $bname = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['bname'] );
    $tpay = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['tpay'] );
    $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn,$_POST['dob'] );

    //file uploading//image name hre
      $image = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
      //image temp name
      $temp_name =  $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];  

      //uploading image to folder
      move_uploaded_file($temp_name,"uploads/salary/$image");
$check = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` where username = '$uname' or email = '$email'";
$crr = mysqli_query($conn , $check);

if (mysqli_num_rows($crr) <=0){


$query ="INSERT INTO `tbl_users` (username, email, password,last_login,created)
   VALUES ('$uname', '$email', '$password',NOW(),NOW());"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $select ="Select user_id from tbl_users where username = '$uname' ";  
    $sr = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sr);
    $userid = $row['user_id'];

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO `tbl_account_details` (`user_id`, `fullname`, `company`, `city`, `country`, `locale`, `address`, `phone`, `phone_2`, `mobile`, `mobile_2`, `skype`, `language`, `departments_id`, `avatar`, `ntn`, `ntn_2`, `cnic`, `business_name`, `researcher`, `age`, `file_no`, `status`, `gender`, `sale_tax_no`, `dob`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `bus_emp_name`, `bus_emp_add`, `resi_add`, `rto`, `zone`, `consultancy`, `name_consultant`, `tax_category`, `activity`, `name_of_city`, `fbr_password`, `fbr_pincode`, `sbr_password`, `email_Add`) VALUES ('$userid', '$fnameq', 'NULL', '$city', 'NULL', 'en_US', 'NULL', '$phone', 'NULL', '$mobile', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'english', '0', '$image', '$ntn', 'NULL', '$cnic', '$bname', '$tpay', '$dob', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', '$dob', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL');";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

if($result2 > 0){

        $response = mysqli_fetch_array( $sr );
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
         $response["response1"]["user-id"] = $row["user_id"];
        $response['status'] = 'Registration Successful,Wait For Admin To Activate Your Account';
         $json =  json_encode($response);
 echo $json;
           exit;
    }
    else{
           $response['status'] = 'Registration Unsuccessful';
            $json =  json_encode($response);
            echo $json;
            exit;


               } 
            }
               else{

                       $response['status'] = 'Username Already Exists';
                       $json =  json_encode($response);
                       echo $json;
                       exit;


               }
         }

?>
```

i am using the same code for login and its working !!
Guide me please so that i can start working on it again!!

Error Logcat:

```
01-09 15:49:12.824 7571-7622/? E/Volley: [292] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                             at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
                                             at com.android.volley.Request.encodeParameters(Request.java:450)
                                             at com.android.volley.Request.getBody(Request.java:436)
                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:260)
                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:234)
                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
                                             at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
                                             at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
01-09 15:49:12.825 7571-7571/? E/MainActivity: Registration Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: share error log...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: okay @Omi  wait..thanks

Comment: I edited my question with error logcat

Comment: you are missing to pass to php parameter like $_POST['txtname'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['strn']

Comment: is this only issue? i will try it.

Comment: this may be issue so try it let me know...

Comment: nopx...still same issue!!

Comment: my registration has 3 steps..so i am using shared preferences to store data and calling them at last activity on register button!!!

Comment: i am stuck here from last two days! and i have no idea for solution

Answer (score 0):

try below code in onErrorResponse()

instead of

```
@Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```

use

```
 @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
 NetworkResponse errorRes = error.networkResponse;
                    String stringData = "";
                    if(errorRes != null && errorRes.data != null){
                        try {
                            stringData = new String(errorRes.data,"UTF-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("Error",stringData);
}
```